# Optimizing computations with nilpotents in a group algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, computer-algebra, group-rings, group-algebras

Of course, I have a very concrete problem at hand, which has been vexing me for about a year now. But let me start with a question that has a better chance of having been answered.

> Let $G$ be a finite group. In my situation, it is the symmetric group, so its irreps can be fairly large but are all defined over $\mathbb Z$.
>
> In the group ring $\mathbb Z\left[G\right]$, I have a nilpotent element $u$. I want to compute its index of nilpotency, i.e., the smallest $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $u^k = 0$.
>
> Is there a fast way to do this, if $G$ is large but $u$ is sparse (i.e., has only few nonzero coefficients)?

The specific case I have in mind is the following. We fix a positive integer $n$. We work in the group algebra $\mathbb Z\left[S_n\right]$ of the $n$-th symmetric group $S_n = \operatorname{Aut}_{\operatorname{Set}}\left(\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}\right)$. For each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, we define the "somewhere-to-below shuffle" element
\begin{align}
t_i = z_{i,i} + z_{i,i+1} + z_{i,i+2} + \cdots + z_{i,n} \in \mathbb Z \left[S_n\right] ,
\end{align}
where $z_{i,j}$ denotes the cycle $\operatorname{cyc}_{i, i+1, \ldots, j} = \left(i,i+1,\ldots,j\right) = s_i s_{i+1} \cdots s_{j-1} \in S_n$ (the latter expression is a reduced expression in terms of the standard Coxeter generators $s_k = \operatorname{cyc}_{k,k+1}$). In [joint work with Nadia Lafrenière](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/s2b1.pdf) ([summary](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/dc2023.pdf)), we have shown that these elements $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ can be simultaneously triangularized (as endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z\left[S_n\right]$), so that their commutators $\left[t_i,t_j\right] = t_i t_j - t_j t_i$ are nilpotent. I'm wondering what their indices of nilpotency are. I conjecture [**EDIT:** This has now been proved; see https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/s2b2.pdf ] that any $i < j$ satisfy
\begin{align}
\left[t_i,t_j\right]^{j-i+1} = 0
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left[t_i,t_j\right]^{n-j+1} = 0
\end{align}
(and perhaps even $\left[t_i,t_j\right]^{n-j} = 0$ when $j < n-1$). Note that the first of these identities implies the other if $j-i \leq n-j$, and vice versa if $j-i \geq n-j$. So far we have been able to prove these two identities in the case when the exponent is $2$, and verify them using SageMath for all $n \leq 11$. But I have reasons to suspect that something might start going wrong around $n = 12$ (e.g., I wouldn't be surprised if the true indices of nilpotency are closer to the Fibonacci numbers $f_{j-i}$ instead of $j-i+1$ in the long run). I have had no success getting SageMath to compute these powers in the cases when they get interesting. The powers of $\left[t_i, t_j\right]$ tend to undergo a combinatorial explosion (with many nonzero coefficients) before they "suddenly" collapse to $0$.

I have tried to use the Artin-Wedderburn-Young isomorphism to replace the group ring (over $\mathbb Q$) by a direct sum of matrix algebras, but it isn't clear to me how useful this is, since the sparseness of the $t_i$ gets lost upon application of this isomorphism. The largest irrep of $S_n$, as far as I understand, is pretty large, so I am not sure how much of a speedup this should give even asymptotically.

If you try to solve my specific problem, keep in mind that you can WLOG assume that $i = 1$ (all other cases reduce to $i = 1$ by embedding smaller symmetric groups into larger ones).

Comment: I'm confused.  I didn't think that these rings had nilpotent elements.  The group algebra $\mathbb QG$ is separable, and hence semisimple, so there cannot be any nilpotent elements there.  The inclusion $\mathbb ZG\hookrightarrow\mathbb QG$ should send nilpotents to nilpotents, and so these elements would have to be in the kernel of this map... but I thought that the inclusion was injective.  Can you give an example of one of these nilpotent elements?

Comment: @SeanSanford: Keep in mind that $G$ is non-abelian, so $\mathbb QG$ is a direct product of matrix rings. Matrix rings have lots of nilpotent elements. For instance, $\left[t_1,t_2\right]$ in $\mathbb ZS_3$ is a nonzero element that squares to $0$.

Comment: @SeanSanford perhaps you were thinking it can't have any nilpotent elements in its center, which is I believe is true.

Comment: the largest degree of an irrep of S_12 is 7700, and 21450 for S_13. If you need another data point, you could brute-force it for S_12 under Artin-Wedderburn as the direct sums make the task embarrassingly parallel (check out the @parallel directive in SAGE), but the dimensions become prohibitively large rather quickly. Hard to say what these elements will look like under Artin-Wedderburn.

Comment: Ah!  Yes, thank you both.